# Naming a not-quite-flatMap method

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I recently created [Argyle](https://github.com/jfkelley/argyle), a small library for parsing command-line arguments in Scala. I'd be happy for anyone to take a look and provide general feedback on it. But there is also one specific issue that sparked some discussion when I [posted on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/6vo6ht/argyle_scala_commandline_argument_parsing/), so I would be interested to hear the thoughts of folks here also. Basically, I have the following trait:

```
trait Arg[+A] {
  def parse(xs: List[String], mode: ArgMode): Try[A]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Try[B]): Arg[B]
}
```

The idea is that an `Arg[A]` handles parsing (and potentially failing to parse) a list of strings into an `A`. The issue is over the name of the `flatMap` method. It's a useful method, for instance, converting an `Arg[String]` to `Arg[Int]` by `.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt))`. But it's not a valid FP Monad flatMap since the parameter type is `A => Try[B]` and not `A => Arg[B]`.

If you view `Arg` as a function `List[String] => Try[A]`, then it is actually pretty identical to `.andThen(_.flatMap(f))`. But I don't know if there's a canonical FP name for an operation like this.

In my mind, pros of naming it `flatMap`:

- Similar enough to other `flatMap` methods that it gives some immediate understanding of how it should function
- Enables for-comprehension with chains of `Try`s and such, that work as expected

Cons:

- Confusing for those who expect `flatMap` always implies monad, since `Arg` is not a monad.
- Potentially confusing that for-comprehensions can't use chains of `Arg`s, but that seems nonsensical anyway, and probably *shouldn't* be allowed.

Any other thoughts, or suggestions for a better name? There is also a `map` method to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider creating an `Arrow` type from `Arg[A]` to `Arg[B]`, something like:

```
import scalaz.Arrow // Also available in Cats    

case class ArgArrow[A, B](run: Arg[A] => Arg[B])

object ArgArrow {
  implicit val arrowInstance: Arrow[ArgArrow] = new Arrow[ArgArrow] {
    def arrTry[A, B](f: A => Try[B]): ArgArrow[A, B] = ???
    def arrOption[A, B](f: A => Option[B]): ArgArrow[A, B] = ???
    // implement other required functions
  }
}
```

With `Arrow`, it will be very easy to assemble different things together, for example, you can easily combine an `A => B`, an `A => Try[C]`, and an `A => Option[D]` into an `ArgArrow[A, (B, C, D)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to move the mapping behavior into the `Arg` for composability

```
import scala.util.Try
trait ArgMode

trait ArgParse[I, O] {
  def parse(x: I, mode: ArgMode): Try[O]

  final def andThen[B](that: ArgParse[O, B]): ArgParse[I, B] = {
    ArgParse((x, mode) => parse(x, mode).flatMap((that.parse(_, mode))))
  }
}

object ArgParse {

  def apply[I, O](f: (I, ArgMode) => Try[O]) = new ArgParse[I, O] {
    override def parse(x: I, mode: ArgMode): Try[O] = f(x, mode)
  }

  def stringsToInt = ArgParse[List[String], Int]((xs, _) => Try(xs.head.toInt))

  def intToInts = ArgParse[Int, Seq[Int]] ((x, _) => Try(1 to x map (_ => x)))

}
```

then compose away

```
scala> ArgParse.stringsToInt.andThen(ArgParse.intToInts).parse(List("5"), new ArgMode {})
res1: scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]] = Success(Vector(5, 5, 5, 5, 5))
```